# Which psychological word describes this situation best?

Tags: terminology

A few years ago, I’ve heard that people have to be in the center if they want to truly enjoy something. For example, when someone really want to enjoy a concert, he or she needs to go to the center of the crowd. It is also true when you work.

Is there any psychological terminology or effect which describes this situation well?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the word center used literally or figuratively?

Comment: It’s used figuratively.

Comment: is [egocentrism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egocentrism) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean an engagement?
If though, a positive psychology have term **flow state** - when you fully immersed. [Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)) is wiki article about it. Or hyperfocus - [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfocus).

Components of flow state:

```
Intense and focused concentration on the present moment

Merging of action and awareness

A loss of reflective self-consciousness

A sense of personal control or agency over the situation or activity

A distortion of temporal experience, one's subjective experience of time is altered

Experience of the activity as intrinsically rewarding, also referred to as autotelicexperience
```

Answer (score 0):

The claim sounds false for any of the meanings I can imagine for 'truly enjoy'. Enjoyment whether contentment or joy will depend on context, expectations, personality, culture, and other factors. It may be more stimulating to be in louder or more crowded settings; in that sense, being in the middle of a crowd could feel more intense than being on the periphery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Since my first language is not English, my question may sounds confusing. I apologize this. What I meant by the question was that it’s not only for ‘entertainments’ like music concert, but it’s for any activity like studying. When you study something, it becomes more fun when you study the core of the study. When you participate discussion, it’s more fun to talk, not to be a bystander.. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you. There are so many meanings for 'center' or 'core' that I don't think this claim can be evaluated. There may feel like there is a stable meaning for the word, but I suggest this is an illusion. See this philosophical explanation for how common terms have no central meaning (see what I did there?): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_resemblance

Comment: PS, this issue is not unique to English.

Answer (score 0):

From the question and comments, I believe the word the OP is asking for and means enjoying something more when being in the center of the happening is **engagement.**

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/engagement), engagement means "a job or period of employment especially as a performer," or "emotional involvement or commitment."

A simpler word would be just **involvement,** which, according to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/involvement), means "the fact or condition of being involved with or participating in something" or "emotional or personal association with someone."

This has nothing to do with being self-centered or egocentric. It means experiencing the event better when you are **actively participating** in it rather than just observing it.